# LINQ sum some column when 2 other column values are the same

Tags: vb.net, linq, sum

i've the following table

```
+-------+--------+----------+
| catid |  name  | quantity |
+-------+--------+----------+
|     1 | table  |       10 |
|     2 | chair  |        5 |
|     2 | chair  |       10 |
|     1 | table  |       10 |
|     2 | chair  |       15 |
|     3 | pencil |       20 |
+-------+--------+----------+
```

using LINQ i want to sum the quanitiy for the rows that have the same name  catid and save this to the same datatable

so the result would be this table

```
+-------+--------+----------+
| catid |  name  | quantity |
+-------+--------+----------+
|     1 | table  |       20 |
|     2 | chair  |       30 |
|     3 | pencil |       20 |
+-------+--------+----------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var result = (from row in YourTable
             group row by new {row.catid, row.name}
             into grp
                    select new
                    {
                        grp.Key.catid,
                        grp.Key.name,
                        Quantity = grp.Sum(row => row.Quantity)
                    }).ToList();
```

Edit: just noticed it's VB tagged.  Sorry for that. Well, should be something like this:

```
Dim result = From row In YourTable
    Group By Key = New With {row.catid, row.name} Into Group
Select New With 
{ 
.Catid = Key.catid, 
.Name =  Key.Name, 
.Quantity =  Group.Sum(Function(x) x.quantity)
}
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks, well i can access the rows only using the field property like row.Field(Of Integer)("catid") and cant get this to work

Comment: You can only apply LINQ to collections that implement IEnumerable. That is, you can't get it to work directly with DataTable or DataSet. But you can use AsEnumerable method to get System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow>. Check this link  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386910.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Artur Udod's answer is fine (and has extra features), but the simple LINQ answer is:

```
Dim result = From row In YourTable
             Group By row.catid, row.name Into Group
             Select catid, name, quantity = Sum(From g In group Select g.quantity)
```

(untested)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the Mark's answer has been successful in this form:

```
Dim result = From row In YourTable
         Group By row.catid, row.name Into Group
         Select catid, name, quantity = (From g In group Select g.quantity).Sum
```